# Print colored text in consoles (Windows, Mac, Linux)

Tags: java, linux, macos, colors, console

I know this question was asked before, but I have some other questions, too.
So, if I use System.err in eclipse, the text is red.
But if I do it outside in eclise with the windows command prompt, everything has the same color.
Now my question, Is there a way to print colored text in each of these consoles?

I tried it with the following line:

```
System.out.println((char)27 + "[34;43mBlue text with yellow background");
```

I've tried it with Windows 10, didn't work.

I've tried it with Linux Ubuntu, did work, but I don't no if it works for all Linux variations.

I have no Mac, so unfortunately I can't try it, but if anybody can try it, help would be nice. (I also don't to if Mac has this command prompt, so I would thank everybody who can tell me more)

If it's possible, I would like to make it without any library, but if It is very much easier or without library really really hard, than It's ok. (And if it's an library I would be happy If you could tell me what I must do if I want to publish my program that contains this Library).

Thanks, abilnf

Comment: Ask one question. Not thirty. [jansi](http://fusesource.github.io/jansi/)

Comment: Those ANSI colour codes https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code should work on most / all Linux terminals, but not on Windows: "The Win32 console did not support ANSI escape sequences at all until Windows 10 Threshold 2."

Answer (score 0):

There is a Java library [JANSI](https://github.com/fusesource/jansi) to achieve this in Windows by rendering ANSI escape sequences.

Here is how you can use it

```
import org.fusesource.jansi.AnsiConsole;
import static org.fusesource.jansi.Ansi.*;
import static org.fusesource.jansi.Ansi.Color.*;

public class Sample

{

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
AnsiConsole.systemInstall();

System.out.println(ansi().fg(RED).a("Hello World").reset()); // Colored 
System.out.println("This is uncolored");

AnsiConsole.systemUninstall();
}
}
```